# Unable to use flume to extract files into hdfs

Tags: hdfs, flume

I am using flume-ng-1.2.0 with cdh3u5. I am simply trying to extract data from a text file and putting it into hdfs.
Here is the Configuration I am using:

```
agent1.sources = tail1
agent1.channels = Channel-2
agent1.sinks = HDFS

agent1.sources.tail1.type = exec
agent1.sources.tail1.command = tail -F /usr/games/sample1.txt
agent1.sources.tail1.channels = Channel-2

agent1.sinks.HDFS.channel = Channel-2
agent1.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://10.12.1.2:8020/user/hdfs/flume
agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

agent1.channels.Channel-2.type = memory
agent1.channels.Channel-2.capacity = 1000
```

and I am running agent by `bin/flume-ng agent -n agent1 -c ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf`

and the logs which I am getting is

```
2012-10-11 12:10:36,626 INFO lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Starting lifecycle supervisor 1
2012-10-11 12:10:36,631 INFO node.FlumeNode: Flume node starting - agent1
2012-10-11 12:10:36,639 INFO nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager: Node manager starting
2012-10-11 12:10:36,639 INFO lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Starting lifecycle supervisor 12
2012-10-11 12:10:36,641 INFO properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Configuration provider starting
2012-10-11 12:10:36,646 INFO properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:conf/flume.conf
2012-10-11 12:10:36,657 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
2012-10-11 12:10:36,670 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
2012-10-11 12:10:36,670 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
2012-10-11 12:10:36,670 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
2012-10-11 12:10:36,671 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: HDFS Agent: agent1
2012-10-11 12:10:36,758 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration  for agents: [agent1]
2012-10-11 12:10:36,758 INFO properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
2012-10-11 12:10:36,800 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitoried counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: Channel-2, registered successfully.
2012-10-11 12:10:36,800 INFO properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: created channel Channel-2
2012-10-11 12:10:36,835 INFO sink.DefaultSinkFactory: Creating instance of sink: HDFS, type: hdfs
2012-10-11 12:10:37,753 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Hadoop Security enabled: false
2012-10-11 12:10:37,896 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitoried counter group for type: SINK, name: HDFS, registered successfully.
2012-10-11 12:10:37,899 INFO nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{tail1=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource@362f0d54 }} sinkRunners:{HDFS=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@4b142196 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{Channel-2=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel@16a9255c} }
2012-10-11 12:10:37,900 INFO nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager: Starting Channel Channel-2
2012-10-11 12:10:37,901 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: Channel-2 started
2012-10-11 12:10:37,901 INFO nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager: Starting Sink HDFS
2012-10-11 12:10:37,905 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: HDFS started
2012-10-11 12:10:37,910 INFO nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager: Starting Source tail1
2012-10-11 12:10:37,912 INFO source.ExecSource: Exec source starting with command:tail -F /usr/games/sample1.txt
```

I don't know where am I doing mistake. As I am a beginner I am not getting anything in hdfs and the flume-agent is kept on running. any suggestion and correction will be very helpful to me ,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that you have set `agent1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.file.Type = DataStream` but the property is `hdfs.fileType` -- see https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink for more info.

I would try with a logger sink -- `sink.type = logger` -- just to see if anything comes through. Also make sure you're getting something when you run that `tail -F` command from your shell.

One more thing, which may be a red herring: there is a backtick (`) at the end of your log message. Maybe that was a paste error, but if not then if that's in your config file I wouldn't be surprised if it caused trouble. The message I am referring to is from the last line in your log:

```
Exec source starting with command:tail -F /usr/games/value.txt`
```

Comment: Thanks mike for your correction in my configuration.I have edited my new configuration and logs.Still i am not able to get anything in hdfs.Using tail -F is giving me my texts in the file.And sorry for the error in log that was my paste error. I will try with logger sink though.